# Is it possible to make a "php injection"?

Tags: php, code-injection

I'm building a web application and I'm concern with security.

Is it a way to make a "php injection", in the same way it is possible to make "SQL injection" ? That means client can send some php code which will be executed on the server.

Until we don't use the "eval" function, I would like to say "no" because when we get a value by $_GET and $_POST, all the data are treated as simple string... But maybe I don't see an obvious attack.

Comment: If you display GET or POST vars without sanitizing, it's possible to inject malicious javascript into a page display that will affect the viewers browser

Comment: Yes, sure) `eval` for example... there are number ways

Comment: you shouldn't let people upload any kind of file to your server. Imagine a person uploading a php file through a form and then request that file when it have been stored at the server.

Comment: php injection can happen from file upload also so u need to make sure that that if u have upload options the files should be in non-executable and folder should not be accessible via the browser.

Comment: Look out for uploading of files in combinition of where those files are stored in an application. Many applications keep an upload folder _inside_ the folder where the applications logic is stored, since this is required by many web hosters. Indeed that can be a huge security thread.

Comment: You may be open to [**Remote File Inclusion attack**](http://securityxploded.com/remote-file-inclusion.php)

Comment: `call_user_func_array("exe".chr(99), array("THIS IS SPARTA", "--all"));`

Comment: I wait for epic, full and historical answer for this))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, not unless you evaluate it with something that might parse and execute PHP. You already mentioned eval, but there are other functions that have eval-like properties (e.g. `preg_replace`, if the attacker manages to inject the `/e` modifier) or can otherwise allow unwanted levels of access (e.g. `system()`).

Also, if an attacker can upload a file and get it interpreted as PHP, he can run PHP code. nginx can be [easily misconfigured](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Passing_Uncontrolled_Requests_to_PHP) in a way that allows attackers to execute PHP code in image files. The same goes for getting your web site to `include()` his code - possibly by overwriting your files with his uploads, or changing the `include()` arguments to point to a remote site (if that is not disabled in php.ini).

Comment: Oh ! I didn't know the trap with asking a file wich does not exist (e.g. ask "folder/img.jpg/Idontexist.php" will execute "folder/img.jpg")... It is so creepy !

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways in which you could, potentially, have a "PHP injection". `eval` is one of them. `shell_exec` and related functions are a risk too (always use `escapeshellarg`!) But the common theme is putting user input somewhere it can be executed. This is the case with SQL injections, where the query is a string that contains user input and is then executed on the MySQL server.

One slightly more obscure example is file uploads. If you allow uploading of files to your server, do NOT allow unfettered access to them! Someone could upload a PHP file, then access it and get full control of your site, so... yeah, be careful with uploads!

Answer (score 0):

You would call it PHP injection if the PHP script ”constructs all or part of a code segment using externally-influenced input from an upstream component, but it does not neutralize or incorrectly neutralizes special elements that could modify the syntax or behavior of the intended code segment”<sup>[[1]](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/94.html)</sup>.

So for PHP as the processor, any function, whose parameter are being interpreted as PHP, directly or indirectly, may be prone to PHP injection. This includes obviously the [`eval` function](http://php.net/eval), but also functions like [`create_function`](http://php.net/create_function), and [`preg_replace` with *PREG_REPLACE_EVAL* modifier](http://php.net/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers#reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.eval).

Furthermore, this also includes routines that generate PHP code for being written to file like configuration files during an application setup. Or routines that execute PHP via `php -r …`, even when escaped via [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg).

Have a look at the [observed examples for *CWE-94: Improper Control of Generation of Code ('Code Injection')*](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/94.html#Observed_Examples).