# Can you "SQL Inject" a PHP Variable Comparison?

Tags: php, security, authentication

So something that I have been wondering about while working on a current project is if a simple variable comparison is in danger of "SQL Injection" type attacks when one of the variables is user entered.

My basic login functionality works by taking the user provided username and using a prepared statement to look it up in the profiles table.  If a record is found, the `profileID` is then retrieved from the record and used to look up the user's password in another permissions table.  If THAT query is successful then the user provided password is `===` against the retrieved password from the database.

So my question is, does that last step pose a risk?  I have tried 'hacking it myself putting through values like `a' == 'a' || 'a` in an attempt to falsely trigger the `$pass === $checkPermRow['pass']` but it doesn't seem to do anything. Am I safe?

Comment: Also another question while I'm at it. The use of prepared statements in PHP was supposed to replace the inherent risks of just 'escaping' a user provided string.  But is it still a good idea to escape the user strings prior to inserting them into a prepared query?

Comment: There are some risks if you already has stored malicious string into the database and lately use it nested query, but most of the adapters are clever enough about this too. You still can retrieve the fields you are worried about and put them in prepared statement. E.g.: `SELECT password FROM users WHERE user = :user` you retrieve `password`, but you are worried about it. `$pass = $row['password']`; `SELECT permission FROM access WHERE user_pass = :user_pass` `$stmt->bindValue(":user_pass", $row['password'], PDO:PARAM_STRING);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use prepared statements and pass the input as parameters to the prepared statement, you’re safe from SQL injections. The parameters should be handled properly and it should not be possible that fragments of the passed parameters are interpreted as SQL code instead of data. That’s the exact point of parameterization, i. e., the separation of code and data parameters.

So it should not be possible to inject anything into the query. However, you should not store the passwords in plaintext but in a irreversible form as a hash using an appropriate hash function.

---

As for your question whether an injection is also possible in PHP itself: Yes, code injection can happen in any code that gets generated dynamically, so even in PHP.

However, you would need not just to generate the code dynamically but also execute it. PHP has some functions that execute PHP), e. g., the [`eval` function](http://php.net/eval). However, you would probably not use constructs like this:

```
if (eval("return '$pass' === '$checkPermRow[pass]';"))
```

This would be vulnerable to [PHP code injection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22898204/53114) and a `a' == 'a' || 'a` would result in something like:

```
return 'a' == 'a' || 'a' === 'password from database';
```

Comment: Thanks Gumbo, but that's not quite what i was asking.  I'm not worried about my queries because at no point does user entered data get put into any query. My question was regarding whether or not this same _type_ of attack could be used for variable comparisons.  So if I have a statement such as **IF ($user_entered_data == check_value)** can I rest assured that this statement is safe from rogue values entered by the user (either intentionally or unintentionally)

Comment: @BenW301 PHP has a separation of data and code as well. Only when you would generate the PHP code dynamically (e. g., `if (eval("'$pass' === '$checkPermRow[pass]'"))`) the mentioned example would be the same for PHP.